# maximo anywhere- offline storage getting cleared after logout

Tags: dataset, maximo-anywhere

I have some data stored in offline db, but its getting cleared during logout.

Once I logout and login again, data is getting cleared. Please advise if any configuration missing.

I have used `ModelService.save(dataset)` to save dataset and `ModelService.all('datasetname')` to fetch dataset

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After logout offline data is available. It was a code issue.